# Python Declaring global variable for threading.thread return type

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I have a multithreaded Python Application which starts thread in 1 function

```
global eventthread

def StartEventCollection(server, port, filtercommand):
   eventthread = threading.Thread(target=ProcessEvents, args=("EventThread", 0)).start()
```

Now, I have another function in which I encounter a failure and want to close the thread

```
def StopEventCollection():
   eventthread.join()
```

My code is not working because my 2nd function is unable to find eventthread defined in function 1.
How can I make eventthread  global?

Comment: use the `global` keyword

Comment: Please create a minimal working example of the problem!

Comment: Tried declaring variable eventthread as global but doesn't seem to help

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved by following change:-
`def StartEventCollection(server, port, filtercommand): global eventthread eventthread = threading.Thread(target=ProcessEvents, args=("EventThread", 0)).start()`